# Focus/Blur to Show/Hide input groups

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a little form with two groups of three inputs.

Only one input is visible for each group.

[image: no input focused]

If I focus an input, all in the same group are shown.

[image: Group1 input focused]

If no input of the group is focused, only the first one should appear.

[image: Group2 input focused]

```js
$('input').focus(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').addClass('focused');
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass('focused');
})
```

This works in Chrome but not in Firefox (please check [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b439u/)).
Both right hand side inputs are hidden before getting the focus.
Seems like events bubbling order is different on both browsers.

Can someone help me to make this work for all browsers ?

Comment: I would think that it might be due to you not removing the `.hide` class when you add the `.focused` class. Try and see if that works.

Comment: That's not the case, `.focused .hide` has the precedence on `.hide`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a slight delay to prevent this.

```
$('input').focus(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('div');
    var timeoutId = $parent.data('tid');

    if (timeoutId) {
        // Aborting the blur
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    $parent.addClass('focused');
}).blur(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('div');

    var tid = setTimeout(function(){
        $parent.removeClass('focused');
    }, 1);

    $parent.data('tid', tid);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b439u/5/